# www-data user cannot access USB drive mounted in /var/www/html/folder

Tags: permissions, php, chmod, web, ownership

I have an Raspberry Pi with mounted USB external drive.

I've mounted this USB (`/dev/sda1`) to `/var/www/html/owncloud/data/drive` as I want to be able to access it from my PHP applications (precisely: owncloud).

My `/etc/fstab/` looks like this:

```
PARTUUID=5e3da3da-01  /boot           vfat    defaults          0       2
PARTUUID=5e3da3da-02  /               ext4    defaults,noatime  0       1
UUID=6D38B7934EF41800 /var/www/html/owncloud/data/drive ntfs defaults,auto,users,rw,nofail,umask=000,allow_other 0 0
```

After reboot, it shows up just fine in WinSCP. I can also list it via terminal (`drwxrwxrwx 1 root root` for `drive` directory):
[image]

Tho, my PHP scripts and owncloud seems not to be able to access the content of this folder.
I guess it's due to permissions problems, as my `drive` folder is owned by `root` and not by `www-data`.

But changing permissions to `www-data` does not work (because it's mounted?). I've also tried the line in `etc/fstab` with `allow_other`. Same goes for `sudo usermod -a -G disk www-data`, as suggested in https://askubuntu.com/questions/988593/www-data-user-cannot-access-mounted-partition

Comment: Does it have to be NTFS or is that just because you didn't reformat it when you first used it?

Comment: @roaima I can re-format it in different filesystem if needed. Tho, I am not sure if that's the reason of problems? I mean, I see it via FTP etc.

Comment: I can't read the text in that image (we ask people [not to post pictures of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/100397)) but if the permissions for the mount point are wrong then that could be why your app can't write to it.

Comment: `drwxrwxrwx 1 root root` - that's for /var/www/html/owncloud/data/drive

Comment: @roaima sure, added.

Comment: `sudo -u www-data`. What error do you get when you turn try to write a file (or directory) on the mounted filesystem? Is it a straight "permission denied"?

Comment: @roaima, Yes, plain "mkdir: cannot create directory ‘aa’: Permission denied" for www-data user. For root user, it works (of course).

Comment: I suspect then that it's something to do with NTFS filesystem permissions. A reformat to (say) `ext4` will make it much more likely your `chmod a=rwx` on the mountpoint will actually do something useful